# Is it possible to test from multiple browsers within Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, flash-builder

After making major (or even minor) changes, I'd like to test in multiple browsers to make sure I haven't broken anything.  Right now, to switch between browsers in Flash Builder, my workflow looks like this:

- Click 'Windows', 'Preferences'
- Navigate to 'General', 'Web Browsers'
- Choose a web browser, hit ok
- Hit play

Ideally, I'd like it to look like this

- Drop down the 'play' button, choose the correct browser-configuration.

However, I can't figure out how to do this Flash Builder without using a nasty batch-file.

Is there a way to built-in to do this?  It seems like testing in multiple browsers would be an extremely common problem, so I find it hard to believe there's nothing built-in for it...

Comment: Why do you need to test in multiple browsers?

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include Eclipse as that is what Flash Builder really built on/around.  That could potentially get you more traffic on the question.  It would also make it more useful to all the Eclipse users out there that don't know what Flash Builder is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set up Eclipse to do this.

In Eclipse (AKA Flash Builder)

1) Select the `Run External Tools` icon (green arrow with small red toolbox) OR `Run` menu -> `External Tools`.

2) Select `External Tools Configuration`.

3) Under the `Location` heading select the `Browse File System` button and browse to the executable for the Browser that you want to use.

4) Under the `Arguments:` header add this `http://localhost:8080/${project_name}/index.html` exactly.  The variable will allow you keep the configuration generic and work for any project.

5) I suggest you give it name like "Chrome - current project index.html"

6) Repeat this process for all the browsers that you wish to test with.

To use this, just select the configuration you created from the `Run External Tools`. (please note that you will need to `Run` it from the Configuration the first time for it to show up in the drop-down)

NOTE: I have confirmed this is available in the Flash perspective of Flash Builder.

There is a move complete description of this process with pics at 
[AVAJAVA Web Tutorials](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-open-a-browser-window-via-eclipse.html).

---

Alternatively you could use [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), to open up multiple browsers.  Using Selenium also has the added benefit of allowing you to set up unit testing (I use the term loosely here) of the UI. (Though I am not sure that last part would work with Flash/Flex)

Here are several links that describe this very situation.

[Abode QA blog](http://abodeqa.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-execute-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-parallel-in-multiple-browser-using-testng-parameter-annotation/)

[running selenium webdriver test cases against multiple browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076971/running-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-against-multiple-browsers)

[Running JUnit Tests On different browsers using Selenium "Automatically"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010506/running-junit-tests-on-different-browsers-using-selenium-automatically)